# Visual Studio 2019 - remove double CTRL+S as a short cut of save file as

Tags: visual-studio-2019

How do I remove the shortcut to save file as when I do ctrl + s twice in a row in VS 2019?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change it in Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard
If you can't that specific setting you can set that keybind as a secondary one for save file and it should erase the other keybind.

For more info about changing keybinds in visual studio here is the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019